# binary operator '*' not implemented for 'cs-list' by 'scalar' operation

Tags: octave

I am getting error from below line, but below line is not in any loop:

```
data.dataAcq_step = (x.datarate_acquired)*(simTime.step); % Acquired data  in
                                                          % a time step
```

> error: binary operator '*' not implemented for 'cs-list' by 'scalar' operations

Inputs are called from two different functions 'x' and 'simTime':

1)

```
n = n+1;
x(n).datarate_acquired = 12e12/(24*60*60);   % data rate of onboard acquired
                                             % data [bit/s]

x.propa_step =  Inf;                         % propagation time step [s]
```

2. simTime.step = min([[x(:).propa_step], y.t_step]);
   y.t_step = 15*60; %(called from another function 'y')

Please suggest on this error.

Comment: Your question is illegible. Please include the full error message and the minimal code required to reproduce the issue, *properly formatted*. See [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't shed much light, since it is not even valid octave syntax, but the error you're getting effectively says that you're trying to multiply a scalar with a [Comma Separated List](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Comma-Separated-Lists.html).

If I had to guess, most likely, you accidentally have a struct array instead of a single struct, and you're trying to access one of its fields, resulting in a comma separated list of that field over all elements in the struct array.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I couldnt provide most of the code as it is complex and lengthy. I tried to change the structure but didnt work. When checked all inputs producing scalar values and still having this error. @Tasos Papastylianou

Comment: Reducing your complex code to the smallest example that reproduces the error is an extremely useful skill! Try. You'll probably figure out the error yourself while doing it. In any case, I think `x.data_acquired` returns a comma-separated list of values instead of a scalar, and that's what's causing your error. Type `x.data_acquired` in your terminal; how many "ans" answers does it spit out? I'm guessing it's more than one.

Comment: Yes, 'x' is a 1x5 struct array. Also 'data' in 'data.dataAcq_step' is also a struct array. 
' x.datarate_acquired
ans = 1.3889e+08
ans = 1.3889e+08
ans = 1.8519e+09
ans = 1.8519e+09
ans = 1.8519e+09 ' 

and 'simTime.step = 60 '. I have to store the result in struct 'data.dataAcq_step'. Please suggest.

Comment: It's not clearly explained what you're trying to do, so I cannot really suggest anything. If what you're trying to do is collect the comma separated list values into an array, for the purpose of multiplying it by a scalar in a vectorised manner, then you can always 'wrap' your cs-list in square brackets. As long as the values are valid values for an array, then this will generate a normal array from those values.

Comment: I tried wrapping it and ended up with error 'scalar cannot be indexed with . . 'data.dataAcq_step = [x.datarate_acquired].*simTime.step; ' @Tasos Papastylianou

Comment: Still looking for a solution .. please suggest @TasosPapastylianou

Comment: Hi @SreedeviPotluri, like I said earlier, it's not clear what you're trying to do, so it is not possible to help further. This is the kind of question where a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help you get better help.